# How to input time from <select> into mysql and have it output am/pm?

Tags: php, mysql, forms

Hey guys so, im doing this form with a  input that will contain the time and i want to make it so that when users choose the time (for example 8:30 AM), it will be stored in mysql, and will be output by php with the exact time (8:30 AM).

Here is the form. A simple select button with increments of 30 on the time.

http://jsfiddle.net/jXVPS/

The main problem is i dont know how mysql will recognize if it is AM/PM?

What values i should put for the select fields, how i would insert it into the mysql database, and have mysql or php recognize wheather it is 1:00 AM or 1:00 PM. Is there some sort of 24 hour clock in mysql that makes it recognize wheather or not it is AM/PM?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's MySQL's time/date stuff.  I think the `TIME` type would be best for you since you don't need a date, and the format you've got for your values should fit well.  I think you can just put them as strings exactly like that.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-types.html

After you submit thru form submission or ajax and your responding PHP page takes over, perform a query with the following string in the PHP:
`"INSERT INTO table (userId, time, ...) VALUES (..., '$inTime', ...)"`

And then echo it out since you want the next page to repeat it.

---

### Response to comment

I figure you mean that wou want `13:00:00` to be `1:00 PM` when you echo it out later right?

Theres probably something you can do with time functions for either PHP or MySQL (PHP below, MySQL above), but I don't know from memory and this is simple enough you can just do it on your own.
http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.datetime.php

```
$time = //get time field from MySQL
list($h, $m, $s) = explode($time, ':');
if ($h > 12) {$h -= 12; $amOrPm = 'PM'}; else {$amOrPm = 'AM';}
if ($h == 0) {$h = 12;}

echo "$h:$m $amOrPm";
```

PS - 13:00:00 is 1pm, not am.

Comment: same question, how will mysql know if it is the time is AM or PM? Or how would i output it as such. For example i have the value 13:00:00 in my select field, how do i make it so that it will parse out 1:00 AM with the value 13:00:00 instead of 13:00 or 1:00.

Comment: MySQL stores in 24 hour style.  The only time it becomes an issue is when you want to output it later and wish to use 12hr w/ AM/PM

Comment: does strtotime() output it the same way? i cant seem to figure out how to use the function to format it into 1:00 pm thought

Comment: an would i be able to format that interget into 1:00pm or is  your code the only way..?

Comment: once you get the timestamp you can use http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php to get to any format you like.

Answer (score 2):

Use [TIME column type](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/time.html):

> **TIME**
>
> A time. The range is '-838:59:59' to '838:59:59'. MySQL displays TIME values in 'HH:MM:SS' format, but allows you to assign values to TIME columns using either strings or numbers.

It will parse the values in your select options nicely.

---

**Edit**: Example of use:

```
// saving in the db
$sql = "
  INSERT INTO table_name SET
  # ...
  name_of_the_time_column = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['start_time']) . "'";

// retrieving from the db
$sql = "
  SELECT id, ..., TIME_FORMAT(name_of_the_time_column, '%h:%i:%s %p') AS formatted_time
  FROM table_name
  # ...
  ";
```

Comment: how will mysql know if it is the time is AM or PM? Or how would i output it as such. For example i have the value 13:00:00 in my select field, how do i make it so that it will parse out 1:00 AM with the value 13:00:00 instead of 13:00 or 1:00.

Comment: @Ben, the TIME type stores the time in 24h system so if you save `14:00:00` from your select, it will know it's PM and if you save `2:00:00` it will know it's AM. If you then want to get back the time in AM/PM format, you can use [TIME_FORMAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format).

Comment: dont i need to use a php function to output the time in the format i want like strtotime()...cant get that to work though

Comment: @Ben, you need strtotime only if you need the timestamp. I'm not really sure what you're asking now. You can normally save `'14:30:00'` that you get from your select as a value in a TIME column. No php processing needed there. And when you're getting it back from the database, you can use `TIME_FORMAT(name_of_the_time_column, '%h:%i:%s %p')` to get the time as a "am/pm"-formatted string. Did I understand you correctly?

Comment: ok well lets say i inserted 14:30:00 into the database i want use this select statement " SELECT * FROM table" and i want php to echo the column with the time. TIME_FORMAT is a mysql function and since my query is "SELECT * FROM TABLE" , wouldnt it be more efficient to have a php function to parse through the TIME column and echo out the correct time?

Comment: Ben - that time format makes the `SELECT` statement return the string exactly the way you want it.  if you use that you don't need to worry about the PHP formatting.  one or the other

Comment: @Ben, please see my editted answer. Even though using an asterisk to match all the columns is not recommended for production, you could use `SELECT *, TIME_FORMAT(name_of_the_time_column, '%h:%i:%s %p') AS formatted_time ...`. But if you want to, you can parse the time with php, there's nothing stopping you ;)

Comment: OK I GOT IT FINALLY. I apologize if i made it seem like it is harder than it really is. Basically there is two ways to do it, mysql and php. And now i know both ways. Phew...thanks guys :D

Answer (score 0):

Not tested :

```
INSERT INTO myTable
SET time = TIME(STR_TO_DATE('8:30:00 AM','%h:%m:%s %p'))
```

Comment: Please note that `%m` specifier is for months, not minutes. Use `%i` for minutes.